# Number of positive integer solutions with constraint

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An efficient method for computing the number of submultisets of size n, of a given multiset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/an-efficient-method-for-computing-the-number-of-submultisets-of-size-n-of-a-giv)

Consider the equation

$$ x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_m = t $$

for some positive integer $t$.

We want to determine the total number of solutions $(x_1,  \ldots , x_m) \in \mathbb N^m$ of this equation which satisfy the constraint $0 \leq x_1 , x_2 , \ldots , x_m \leq n$ (here $n$ is some fixed positive integer).

(If it would help you may assume that $t$ is a multiple of $n$, i.e. $t = r \cdot n$ for some positive integer $r$.)

I tried using generating functions. I think that $ \left( \sum_{i=0}^n z^i \right)^m $ is its generating function. But from this I cannot deduce a formula. If we write this formal series as $ \sum_{i} a_i z^i $ then I want to calculate the term $a_t$, in which I do not succeed.

Comment: Title asks for *positive* integer solutions, body allows $x_i\ge0$ --- you should fix this inconsistency. Anyway, this question has been asked and answered here multiples times, mostly as combinatorics or discrete-math. Might be worth searching the site for a previous occurrence.

Comment: See also the questions in the Linked list at 4643.