# Which sum shows up most often when you roll 10 dice?

Tags: probability

Which sum shows up most often when you roll 10 dice?

Comment: Please turn off caps lock when you write the title.  What have you tried-do you know the answer for 2 dice?

Comment: please note that this is at least the fourth time in the recent days another member of the site has requested that you not to use all caps in the question title. Consider this your moderator warning. Any further abuse will result in graduated suspension from the site.

Comment: How many sides do your dice have?

Answer (score 5):

The *sum* that shows up most often when you roll 10 dice is **35**.

Are you also interested to see a reason why this is so?

Comment: I am interested

Comment: @ajbeaven: I think [Yuval Filmus suggestion for a proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/which-sum-shows-up-most-often-when-you-roll-10-dice/29151#29151) is very good. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632/367).

Answer (score 4):

The key to this question is the concept of unimodality (q.v.).

Try to prove by induction that if you take the sum of $n \geq 2$ cubes then the distribution has the following form:

- It is supported (has non-zero probability) on the numbers $n, \ldots, 6n$.
- It is symmetric around $3.5n$.
- It is unimodal: the sequence of probabilities increases monotonically until it reaches its mode (the most probable value), then decreases monotonically.
- If $n$ is even then the mode is unique (and so $3.5n$).
- If $n$ is odd then there are two modes ($\lfloor 3.5n \rfloor$ and $\lceil 3.5n \rceil$).

If you find the proof difficult, try again with two-sided dice.

Of course, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the distribution will approach (in some sense) a Gaussian, but I'm not sure this is enough to prove anything specific about the mode (other than its asymptotics).